# Windows 8.1 does not remember credentials of network location

Tags: windows-8.1, network-shares, shell-script

I have a bunch of computers running Windows 8,1 connected by LAN to one central server that runs Server 2012 R2. I have all my scripts stored on the server, so to be able to run them from the other machines I added the scripts folder as a network location to the other machines.

My problem is that after every reboot trying to run a script (with PowerShell) that is stored on the server does not work, and I have to manually enter the mapped network location from File explorer, enter the credentials again and only then it works.

Every time I do that I check "Remember username and password", and yet I have to do it again after the next reboot.

Hope I was clear :) Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: As a temporary fix whilst you work on a proper solution, create a user with privileges to the share, and map using a local script "net use x: \\server\share /user:domain\user password - This method stores the password in a totally unsecure format.

Comment: add the credentials to the password manager in Windows: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/31797/windows-8-manage-saved-passwords-for-applications/

Comment: Is the issue that the credentials are those of a different user or domain on the server (vs local machine)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mapping a drive in file explorer?

Assuming the issue is with needing a different user's credentials to access the server's mapped location, try this: (This is more of a work-around than a solution, and exploiting a bug rather than a feature, but see below)

1. In Windows, add the remote network share as a mapped drive
2. When in the `map network drive` window, check `Reconnect at sign-in` and `Connect using different credentials`
   [image]
3. Enter appropriate server information and drive letter
4. It will prompt you for credentials - enter the *other* (server) account credentials and check remember my credentials
5. It should fail to connect since it is not the credentials of your local account, but *let it fail* and cancel out.
6. Reboot your machine, (letting your script to add the network drive run)

If I explained this right, it will look like a normal mapped drive in file explorer, but be using the credentials of the other account when accessed in file explorer. Try your script now.